# browsing nested state and ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some nested states (the app is basically a multi-step form) and a parent state which keeps the main data model.

This is an example of nested state:

```
<input type="radio" label="item1" value="item1" ng-model="model.type" ng-click="next='1-1'" group="type" required /><br>
<input type="radio" label="item2" value="item2" ng-model="model.type" ng-click="next='1-2'" group="type" required />

<button ng-click="goToNext(next)">next</button>
```

Obviously if I click on a radio button `next` gets defined with ng-click and `goToNext(next)` works. But if I browse around some other states and come back here `$scope.model.type` is still defined but `$scope.next` isn't. What's the most clean way to keep `$scope.next` "re-executing" ng-click?
(I should replace this in dozens of forms..so it have to be very simple)

Comment: how about saving a variable called $scope.prev, $scope.current, $scope.next in the parent controller, and when going next play around with them?

Comment: since it's a multi-step form, prev and next would be overwrited each step, and keep those 3 for each step it's a plain way to an headache. Maybe there is no angular way. I would go in linked List way.